# Three numbers with low and high digit sum

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

Find three positive integers with the following two properties:

1. The sum of any two of them has digit sum less than 15
2. The sum of all three integers has digit sum more than 200

Comment: By sum do you mean multiplication?

Comment: Exclusively that is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a possible answer which I think suggests the general strategy

> 4554554554554554554554554554554554554555
>  5455455455455455455455455455455455455455
>  5545545545545545545545545545545545545545

The pairwise sums are

> 10010010010010010010010010010010010010010
>  10100100100100100100100100100100100100100
>  11001001001001001001001001001001001001000 (all digit sums are 14)

While the overall sum is

> 15555555555555555555555555555555555555555 (digit sum 201)

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it.

Answer (score 5):

Take these three numbers:

> $$a = 4444444444444\ 5555555555555\ 5555555555555\ 5\\b = 5555555555555\ 4444444444444\ 5555555555555\ 5\\c = 5555555555555\ 5555555555555\ 4444444444444\ 5$$
>  They all consist of three blocks of 13 digits, of which one is all fours and the rest all fives, followed by an extra five.

The pairwise sums are:

> $$a+b = 1\ 0000000000000\ 0000000000000\ 1111111111111\ 0\\b+c = 1\ 1111111111111\ 0000000000000\ 0000000000000\ 0\\c+a = 1\ 0000000000000\ 1111111111111\ 0000000000000\ 0$$
>  The sum of any two of them gives a number with a leading $1$ and block of thirteen $1$s, for a digit sum of $14$.

The sum of all three is:

> $$a+b+c = 1\ 5555555555555\ 5555555555555\ 5555555555555\ 5$$
>  which is a one followed by $40$ fives, for a digit sum of $201$.